# 18.04 - How to make the button from wired headphone to have actions when pressed?

Tags: sound, headphones, microphone

I have a SONY MDR-XB450 wired (non USB) headphone and it has a button that, when pressed, stops and plays youtube videos and has some other actions in my Macbook. And I can use the headphones microphone to answer Skype calls and such.

How can I make it work properly on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: In a terminal window, `journalctl --follow`. Then plug in the headphone, push the button. The log messages should give you hints. If the system doesn't see the button push, sorry, you lose.

Comment: Yeah, nothing happened.